# Upgrading from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6: Fatal error: Interface 'Laminas\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface' not found

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.6, magento-upgrade

Im trying to upgrade a Magento 2 site from 2.2.2 to the latest 2.3.  I've got up to 2.2.5 so far without issues.

When moving from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6 I am getting a fatal error when running `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

```
Fatal error:  Interface 'Laminas\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface' not found in /var/www/html/setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/LazyControllerAbstractFactory.php
```

I've added the `Zend\\Mvc\\Controller` line to the autoload PSR-4 section in the `composer.json` file as suggested elsewhere on the internet.

Here's the steps I follow to update (from a working 2.2.5):

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update
composer update
composer dumpautoload
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
composer dumpautoload
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Its at the `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` step where I get the fatal error.

AFAICT the Laminas ServiceManager AbstractFactoryInterface isn't anywhere in the Vendor dir.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: there is no reason why you cannot upgrade directly from 2.2.5 to 2.3.x. If you are using REDIS make sure you also flush the redis caches before running setup:upgrade / compile

Comment: @paj I tried that first but got problems with `Could not create an acl object:`.  Figured an incremental update might help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was caused by not following an incremental update path from 2.2.2.  Initially I tried to go to 2.3.x and added the `Zend\\Mvc\\Controller` line to `composer.json`.  I then left this line in the composer file when starting the migration from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6.

Removing the line, removing `vendor/` and `composer.lock` and starting the migration again worked.